# Jquery logic if x checkboxes ticked show div quiz

Tags: jquery, if-statement, logic, show-hide

I know this is a simple and lame thing. I need to build a small form where if the user checks 1 checkbox show div a, if two are checked show div b and if three or more are checked show div c.

Any ideas on a simple jQuery way of doing this, I have tried and am overcomplicating this to no avail.

Thanks in advance and sorry for a nooby question!

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count get the length of matches, then handle that with a `switch` or `ifs`

```
handle_number_checked($(":checked").length);
```